# Linearity of the Riemann integral with complex valued functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to verify the following facts for Complex integrals assuming that this works for real integrals:

> Let $f,g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$.
>   (a) $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)+g(t)\,dt=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\,dt+\int_{a}^{b}g(t)\,dt$
>   (b) $a\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\,dt=\int_{a}^{b}af(t)\,dt$

(a) Taking advantage of the linearity of the integral within real numbers.
$\int_a^b f(t)+g(t)\,dt=\int_a^b u_f(t)+iv_f(t)+u_g(t)+iv_g(t)\,dt=\int_a^b u_f(t)+iv_f(t)\,dt+\int_a^b u_g(t)+iv_g(t)\,dt=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt+\int_a^b g(t)\,dt$

(b) $a\int_a^b f(t)\,dt=(x+iy)\int_a^b u(t)+iv(t)\,dt=(x+iy)\int_a^b u(t)\,dt+(x+iy)i\int_a^b v(t)\,dt=x\int_a^b u(t)\,dt+iy \int_a^b u(t)\,dt+ix\int_a^b v(t)\,dt-y\int_a^b v(t)\,dt=\int_a^b xu(t)\,dt+i\int_a^b xv(t)\,dt+i\int_a^b yu(t)\,dt-\int_a^b yv(t)\,dt=\int_a^b xu(t)\,dt-\int_a^b y v(t)\,dt+i \int_a^b x v(t)\,dt+i\int_a^b yu(t)\,dt=\int_a^b a f(t)\,dt$

Comment: What's your question ? Your straightforward calculation seems to be the proof wanted

Comment: I want to make sure its correct.

Comment: I lack confidence with (b).  I guess this seems like a bizzare way to approach proving this.

Comment: Calculation is a proof in itself. If it is correct you can be pretty sure that your proof is valid. Some things just need to be calculated is math sometimes ;-)

Comment: I would just add a simple thing in between the last '=' Something like $\int_a^b xu(t)\,dt-\int_a^b y v(t)\,dt+i \int_a^b x v(t)\,dt+i\int_a^b yu(t)\,dt = \int_a^b Re(a f(t)) + i \int_a^b Im(a f(t))\,dt = \int_a^b af(t)\, dt$

Comment: @Theta30 what do you mean ? I just said: 1. calculation is a valid proof if correct, 2. in math calculation has to be made sometimes

Comment: Would it be appropriate to use the Real and Imaginary functions that you used in (a)?

Comment: @abet don't you just did it ?

Comment: I meant using the $Re$ and $Im$.

Comment: @Theta30 thanks for correcting the typo but for 1. I don't get your point about rigour as my opinion about calculation being a valid rigorous proof (if right) still holds

Comment: @abet you defined $u(t)=Re(f(t))$ and $v(t)=Im(f(t))$ implicitly :-) so it's the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In math we sometimes need just to 'compute' things out to 'prove' two objects are the same.
I our case we want to prove that $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)+g(t)\,dt$ gives the same complex number as $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\,dt+\int_{a}^{b}g(t)\,dt$
Your calculation, which uses the linearity of the real Integral is valid as we can split any complex function $f(t)$ in two parts:$$f(t)=Re(f(t))+i\,Im(f(t))=:u(t)+i\,v(t)$$where $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are real valued functions.
Now for the second part you should maybe show that if $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$ then it holds that:$$z\cdot w=(Re(z)+i\,Im(z))\cdot(Re(w)+i\,Im(w))=(Re(z)\cdot  Re(w)-Im(z)\cdot Im(w))+i\,(Re(z)\cdot Im(w)+Im(z)\cdot Re(w))=:c\in \mathbb{C} \tag{1}$$
and then your last '$=$' also holds as:$$\int_a^b a f(t)\,dt\overset{(1)}{=}\int_a^b (Re(a)\cdot  Re(f(t))-Im(a)\cdot Im(f(t)))+i\,(Re(a)\cdot Im(f(t))+Im(a)\cdot Re(f(t)))\,dt \overset{linearity\, of\, \mathbb{R}\, Integral}{=}\int_a^b Re(a)\cdot  Re(f(t))\,dt-\int_a^b Im(a)\cdot Im(f(t))\,dt+i\,\int_a^b Re(a)\cdot Im(f(t))\,dt+i\,\int_a^b Im(a)\cdot Re(f(t))\,dt \overset{definition}{=} \int_a^b xu(t)\,dt-\int_a^b y v(t)\,dt+i \int_a^b x v(t)\,dt+i\int_a^b yu(t)\,dt$$

Comment: My other concern, and its probably minor, was how I quickly just shifted the integral sign.  I was worried that there were intermediary steps that I skipped.  The fact that I'm trying to prove seems obvious, so I'm worried about skipping the important details.

Comment: As I see things your calculations seems very clear and no important detail was omitted, beside the steps written in this answer.